# CodeJam 2021 Qualifier Round Moons and Umbrellas Algorithm Explanation

Tags: python, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I was trying to understand the solution to the [codejam problem](https://codingcompetitions.withgoogle.com/codejam/round/000000000043580a/00000000006d1145) mentioned by the title. Specifically the third part for "extra credits".
This is the [solution](https://github.com/kamyu104/GoogleCodeJam-2021/blob/main/Qualification%20Round/moons_and_umbrellas.py) by "kamyu104" from Github.

```
# Copyright (c) 2021 kamyu. All rights reserved.
#
# Google Code Jam 2021 Qualification Round - Problem B. Moons and Embrellas 
# https://codingcompetitions.withgoogle.com/codejam/round/000000000043580a/00000000006d1145
#
# Time:  O(N)
# Space: O(1)
#

def moons_and_umbrellas():
    X, Y, S = raw_input().strip().split()
    X, Y = int(X), int(Y)
    dp = {}
    prev = None
    for c in S:
        new_dp = {}
        for i, j, cost in [('C', 'J', Y), ('J', 'C', X)]:
            if c == j:
                new_dp[i] = INF
            elif prev is None:
                new_dp[i] = 0
            elif prev == i:
                new_dp[i] = dp[i]
            elif prev == j:
                new_dp[i] = dp[j]+cost
            elif prev == '?':
                new_dp[i] = min(dp[i], dp[j]+cost)
        dp = new_dp
        prev = c
    return min(dp.itervalues())

INF = float("inf")
for case in xrange(input()):
    print 'Case #%d: %s' % (case+1, moons_and_umbrellas())
```

The programming problem in a nutshell is given a string of
C's and J's, for example, CCJCJ??JC or JCCC??CJ, the question marks should be replaced by either C or J. Minimize the cost of transitioning from C->J or J->C. The two types of transitions have different costs.

The problem is I can't understand the intuition behind the algorithm by kamyu104... I've been following the values on a whiteboard, but I can't get it... Please help! Thank you.

My own code is shown below... I followed the analysis portion of the question provided by Google but it is TLE. I know that we can use memoization, but I don't know where to put it in my code...

```
import sys
def help_cody(mystring): #With the help of analysis tab
  global X
  global Y

  if(len(mystring) <= 1):
    return 0
  else:
    mylist = list(mystring)
    C_string = mylist.copy()
    J_string = mylist.copy()

    if(mystring[0] == '?'):
      C_string[0] = 'C'
      J_string[0] = 'J'
      C_string = "".join(C_string)
      J_string = "".join(J_string)

      return min(help_cody(C_string), help_cody(J_string))
    else:
      if(mystring[0] == mystring[1]): #Same characters for the first two.
        return help_cody(mystring[1:])
      else: #Different Characters
        if((mystring[0], mystring[1]) == ('C','J')):
          return X + help_cody(mystring[1:])
        if((mystring[0], mystring[1]) == ('J','C')):
          return Y + help_cody(mystring[1:])
        if(mystring[1] == '?'):
          C_string[1] = 'C'
          J_string[1] = 'J'
          C_string = "".join(C_string)
          J_string = "".join(J_string)

          return min(help_cody(C_string), help_cody(J_string))


if __name__ == "__main__":
  sys.setrecursionlimit(10**6)
  testcase = int(input())
  for test in range(1, testcase+1):

   X, Y, mystring = input().split()
   X = int(X) #Cost for CJ
   Y = int(Y) #Cost for JC

   print("Case #" + str(test) + ": " + str(help_cody(mystring)))
```

Comment: What parts *do* you understand?

Comment: Hi, thank you for replying. I don't understand why for each character you check the two triplets and how they eventually reach the optimal answer...

Comment: Is it the "Extra Credit" part that you're trying to solve? It would be helpful to mention this, as it's buried deep in the linked page and I didn't realise at first. (The non-extra-credit part of the question has a very simple solution based on the observation that a block of consecutive `?` characters with opposite characters on either side must have at least one J->C or C->J transition, and that this is optimal; `?`-blocks surrounded by two Js or two Cs are optimally set to that same character.)

Comment: Yes! It's the extra credit part. Thank you for notifying me; I have made edits to my post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This rather terse code implements a dynamic programming algorithm that has been optimised to reduce the space usage from O(n) to O(1). First I'll describe an equivalent DP and how it can be computed, and then show how the many separate cases it needs to handle can be viewed as instances of a smaller number of more general "case templates", which kamyu's code exploits for concision.

### A correct but verbose DP algorithm

The question frames the problem as finding a minimum-cost way to replace each "?" character with a J or C, but we can alternatively frame it as finding a minimum-cost way to replace *all* characters of the input string S, provided that we never change a J to a C or vice versa -- that is, we can imagine ourselves "replacing" an existing J with another J, or an existing C with another C. In fact, that "provided" clause can even be removed: We can get what we want by permitting all possible replacements, including a J to be changed to a C or vice versa, but prevent these undesirable changes from actually appearing in any optimal solution by penalising them with enormous costs.

Let's define the function f(m, a) to be **the minimum cost of a solution to the subproblem consisting of the first m+1 characters of the input string S, under the assumption that we replace the final (i.e., (m+1)-th) character with a**, which must be either "J" or "C". (Why m+1 and not m? That just makes code with 0-based array indices simpler.) Replacements that leave this character unchanged (J->J or C->C) are allowed, as are replacements of "?" characters to either J or C. The way we will prevent changing an existing J to a C or vice versa is to assign infinite cost to such a replacement -- this will result in this choice never being taken, since another lower-cost choice is always available.

We can compute values of f(m, a) as follows. I'll use Python-like pseudocode that writes to a DP matrix `dp[][]`.

The highest-priority rule is that we should always assign infinite cost to any attempt to change a hardwired letter to the other letter. Other than that, the cost of assigning a particular letter depends on the preceding letter -- unless there is no preceding letter because we are at the very start, in which case we know that the cost is zero:

```
if S[m] == "C" && m == 0:
    dp[m]["C"] = 0
    dp[m]["J"] = INF    # Heavily penalise attempt to change hardwired C to J
if S[m] == "J" && m == 0:
    dp[m]["C"] = INF    # Heavily penalise attempt to change hardwired J to C
    dp[m]["J"] = 0
if S[m] == "?" && m == 0:
    dp[m]["C"] = 0
    dp[m]["J"] = 0
```

If we are not at the start, then the preceding letter might be hardwired, in which case we know how much it will cost when considered in combination with whatever we decide to replace the current letter with. First let's consider the cases where the current letter is also hardwired, in which case attempts to change it to the other letter need to be penalised:

```
if S[m] == "C" && m > 0 && S[m-1] == "C":
    dp[m]["C"] = dp[m-1]["C"]
    dp[m]["J"] = INF
if S[m] == "C" && m > 0 && S[m-1] == "J":
    dp[m]["C"] = dp[m-1]["J"]+costJC
    dp[m]["J"] = INF
if S[m] == "J" && m > 0 && S[m-1] == "C":
    dp[m]["C"] = INF
    dp[m]["J"] = dp[m-1]["C"]+costCJ
if S[m] == "J" && m > 0 && S[m-1] == "J":
    dp[m]["C"] = INF
    dp[m]["J"] = dp[m-1]["J"]
```

When the previous letter is hardwired but the current letter is "?", there are no INFs because we are allowed to replace the current letter with whatever we want:

```
if S[m] == "?" && m > 0 && S[m-1] == "C":
    dp[m]["C"] = dp[m-1]["C"]
    dp[m]["J"] = dp[m-1]["C"]+costCJ
if S[m] == "?" && m > 0 && S[m-1] == "J":
    dp[m]["C"] = dp[m-1]["J"]+costJC
    dp[m]["J"] = dp[m-1]["J"]
```

If that preceding letter is "?", we could replace it with either "J" or "C", so we can pick whichever gives us the lower cost:

```
if S[m] == "C" && m > 0 && S[m-1] == "?":
    dp[m]["C"] = min(dp[m-1]["C"], dp[m-1]["J"]+costJC)
    dp[m]["J"] = INF
if S[m] == "J" && m > 0 && S[m-1] == "?":
    dp[m]["C"] = INF
    dp[m]["J"] = min(dp[m-1]["C"]+costCJ, dp[m-1]["J"])
if S[m] == "?" && m > 0 && S[m-1] == "?":
    dp[m]["C"] = min(dp[m-1]["C"], dp[m-1]["J"]+costJC)
    dp[m]["J"] = min(dp[m-1]["C"]+costCJ, dp[m-1]["J"])
```

Verify that for every possible value of `m`, running the above code will assign to `dp[m]["C"]` and to `dp[m]["J"]` exactly once each, and that what it assigns is correct. We could build a correct O(n)-time DP algorithm that puts this code inside a `for m in range(len(S))` loop, and then returns `min(dp[len(S)-1]["C"], dp[len(S)-1]["J"])`. Well, **kamyu's code is basically just this algorithm**, but with (1) space usage reduced from O(n) to O(1), (2) some "symmetries" in the updates factored out, and (3) some long `if` conditions made implicit by using `elif`s instead.

### From O(n) space to O(1) space

The first and most important change we can make is to notice that the recurrence relation for calculating `dp[m][...]` never needs to reach back further than `dp[m-1][...]`, so it suffices to keep just the `dp[]` values for the previous `m` value (rather than for all `m` values seen until now). We can achieve this by dropping the first dimension of the `dp[]` array, interpreting `dp["J"]` as `dp[m-1]["J"]`, etc., and using a new dictionary, `new_dp`, for storing what we used to store in `dp[m]`. We set `dp` to this at the end of each iteration. Doing this drops space usage from O(n) to O(1). At this point, the algorithm is already asymptotically optimal (any algorithm must take at least O(n) time to read the input, and at least O(1) space) -- the remainder is just making it tidier/prettier.

### Update symmetries

We can factor out the INF penalties. If we add the following code at the top of the main loop, we can get rid of the 8 code lines above that assign INF:

```
if S[m] == "C":
    new_dp["J"] = INF
    break
if S[m] == "J":
    new_dp["C"] = INF
    break
```

The next thing to notice is that, in all the above `if` statements that begin with `if S[m] == "C"`, there is a corresponding `if` statement that begins with `if S[m] == "J"` with a very similar structure -- essentially, all "C"s are replaced with "J"s and vice versa, and all `costJC`s become `costCJ`s and are applied in slightly different places. Instead of manually writing down both statements, kamyu writes them just once each, in a general "template" form, inside a loop that loops through the 2 different ways of "expanding" them. That's what the innermost `for i, j, cost...` loop is doing.

### if -> elif

Finally, kamyu's code aggressively replaces long lists of ANDed conditions in a sequence of `if` statements with shorter conditions in a chain of `elif`s. Basically, code like

```
if cond1: foo()
elif cond2: bar()
elif cond3: baz()
```

is equivalent to

```
if cond1: foo()
if !cond1 && cond2: bar()
if !cond1 && !cond2 && cond3: baz()
```

(assuming absence of side-effects in evaluating `cond1` and `cond2`). Although using a long chains of `elif`s can make code harder to understand, since you need to keep track of which conditions have already been determined to be false, provided that it ends with an `else` clause (which kamyu's doesn't, but anyway), overall it's a good way to communicate quickly (or convince yourself) that exactly one of the cases will be hit, which is one of the basic requirements for correctness of this kind of DP algorithm.

Notice in particular that if the first `if` in the chain in kamyu's code does not execute, from there on down we know that we are allowed to write letter `i` at the current position -- either because that's the letter that's already there, or because a "?" is there.

After applying all these transformations to the original, verbose DP I described, we recover kamyu's algorithm.

Comment: I just wanted to say thank you very much for the thorough explanation. It was really clear for a beginner to see what you were meaning. Thank you! I originally thought that if it's DP, then I'd have to use a recursive function, but like I mentioned above it became TLE. Do you have any thoughts of my usage of a recursive function(how it could be better)?

Comment: Thanks, glad to hear it :) DPs can always be written in a recursive way, but they can often also be written in an iterative "bottom-up" way in which solutions to subproblems are computed and stored in a table in a specific order that is known to work (meaning here that we will always have computed and stored the solutions for `f[m-1][...]` by the time we get to computing solutions for `f[m][...]`). kamyu's code uses the bottom-up approach, which is often faster by a small constant factor because it avoids having to set up and take down stack frames for each subproblem. ...

Comment: ... Your algorithm is recursive, but isn't DP because it doesn't store and reuse solutions to subproblems it has solved before. It will take time exponential in the string length. Happily, any recursive algorithm can be turned into DP easily: In your case, just (1) create a new global dictionary `memo`, (2) insert a `memo[mystring] = XYZ` before every `return XYZ`, and (3) add the following right at the top of `help_cody()`: `if mystring in memo: return memo[mystring]`. ...

Comment: ... The resulting DP algorithm will be quadratic-time, not linear-time, because it takes linear time to solve each subproblem due to the string copies you perform. kamyu's DP algorithm, and the verbose one I described, take only constant time per subproblem because they work with integer indices into an unchanging string, and most operations on integers take only constant time. I suggest seeing if you can rework your algorithm to avoid string copies (note that recursively calling `help_cody(some_string)` implicitly does a string copy). In any case, quadratic is MUCH faster than exponential :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I changed my code to have the dp memo, and now it is accepted by CodeJam. Sorry for the late reply, and thank you once again. It makes sense now...