# How to convert the recursive solution to "Moons and Umbrellas" to DP?

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming, bottom-up

I'm trying to come up with a DP solution to [Moons and Umbrellas](https://codingcompetitions.withgoogle.com/codejam/round/000000000043580a/00000000006d1145#problem) from Code Jam's Qualification Round 2021. Below is my working recursive solution, based on their [analysis](https://codingcompetitions.withgoogle.com/codejam/round/000000000043580a/00000000006d1145#analysis):

```
import sys
from functools import lru_cache

sys.setrecursionlimit(5000)

T = int(input())

for case in range(1, T+1):
    X, Y, S = input().split()
    X = int(X)
    Y = int(Y)
    S = tuple(S)

    @lru_cache(maxsize=128)
    def cost(S):
        if len(S) <= 1:
            return 0

        if S[0] == '?':
            return min(cost(('C',) + S[1:]), cost(('J',) + S[1:]))

        if S[0] != '?' and S[1] == '?':
            return min(cost((S[0],) + ('C',) + S[2:]), cost((S[0],) + ('J',) + S[2:]))

        if S[0] == S[1]:
            return cost(S[1:])

        if S[0] == 'C' and S[1] == 'J':
            return X + cost(S[1:])

        if S[0] == 'J' and S[1] == 'C':
            return Y + cost(S[1:])

    print(f'Case #{case}: {cost(S)}')
```

The problem in a nutshell is given a string of `C`'s, `J`'s, and `?`s (e.g. `CCJCJ??JC` or `JCCC??CJ`), the question marks should be replaced by either `C` or `J`. Minimize the cost of transitioning from `C`to `J` or vice versa. The two types of transitions have different costs.

How do I convert it to a DP solution using the bottom-up approach?

Comment: dynamic programming is just saving the calculations inside a `list` or something, and if the value is already there, you don't compute it again. What seems to be the issue?

Comment: @Mahrkeenerh: if it's so easy, why not post an answer and get some upvotes?

Comment: @planetp Maybe because that would require taking the time to understand your code, when you didn't even attempt to explain what problem your code was solving, nor how it worked. The terse names of the variables, `S` and `T`, are not particularly self-explanatory.

Comment: @Stef You can see the problem by the link in the OP. The names follow the input description.

Comment: @planetp We cannot believe that Google-driven site will keep something for many years, so it is worth to add problem description here

Comment: No need for dynamic programming here.  Just remove the '?'s, and measure the cost of the resulting string.

Comment: @MattTimmermans X or Y can be negative, so it may be desirable to have more CJ or JCs.

Comment: @Kolmar Ah, I missed that.  Still don't need DP, though, since each gap can be considered separately.

Comment: @MattTimmermans the Analysis on the site claims dp is needed when X and Y can be negative. Could you please help me/us understand the alternative method you're suggesting?

Comment: @גלעדברקן When there's a letter on both sides, If (X+Y) < 0, then fill each sequence of `?`s to create as many transitions as possible.  Otherwise, fill each sequence of `?`s to create as few transitions as possible (just replicate the letter on either side).   For `?`s at the end, you need to consider whether you can make an isolated X or Y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution works for all 3 Test sets:

```
T = int(input())

C, J = 0, 1
INF = float('inf')

for case in range(1, T+1):
    X, Y, S = input().split()
    X = int(X)  # CJ
    Y = int(Y)  # JC

    dp = [[None, None] for _ in range(len(S))]

    for i, c in enumerate(S):
        if i == 0:
            if c == 'C':
                dp[i][C] = 0
                dp[i][J] = INF
            elif c == 'J':
                dp[i][J] = 0
                dp[i][C] = INF
            elif c == '?':
                dp[i][C] = 0
                dp[i][J] = 0
        else:
            if c == 'C':
                dp[i][J] = INF
                if S[i-1] == 'C':
                    dp[i][C] = dp[i-1][C]
                elif S[i-1] == 'J':
                    dp[i][C] = dp[i-1][J] + Y
                elif S[i-1] == '?':
                    dp[i][C] = min(dp[i-1][C], dp[i-1][J] + Y)
            elif c == 'J':
                dp[i][C] = INF
                if S[i-1] == 'C':
                    dp[i][J] = dp[i-1][C] + X
                elif S[i-1] == 'J':
                    dp[i][J] = dp[i-1][J]
                elif S[i-1] == '?':
                    dp[i][J] = min(dp[i-1][J], dp[i-1][C] + X)
            elif c == '?':
                if S[i-1] == 'C':
                    dp[i][C] = dp[i-1][C]
                    dp[i][J] = dp[i-1][C] + X
                elif S[i-1] == 'J':
                    dp[i][C] = dp[i-1][J] + Y
                    dp[i][J] = dp[i-1][J]
                elif S[i-1] == '?':
                    dp[i][C] = min(dp[i-1][C], dp[i-1][J] + Y)
                    dp[i][J] = min(dp[i-1][J], dp[i-1][C] + X)

    print(f'Case #{case}: {min(dp[-1])}')
```

Comment: I'm sorry I lead you down this track :( I don't think this kind of state formulation can work. To formulate bottom-up, I would suggest following Matt's suggestion to consider each sequence of question marks and their surrounding characters separately, where the choices to minimise are very few. Think of the rule for each scenario since there are so few.

Comment: @גלעדברקן I think it's possible to make this approach work, as it's quite similar to another working [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67250158/275088) to this very problem.

Comment: Consider this input, `20 -28 C?C` for which the code returns 0, which is clearly wrong. If you could understand how to fix that, perhaps we'd be good to go :)

Comment: Yep, turns out to be a 1-char fix :) Thanks for this input! BTW, it's weird that it worked with both Test set 1 & Test set 2. It seems the quality of test data is not very good..

Comment: Really, this passes all the tests? Wow, that's great! In that case, I'm glad I lead you down this path :)

Comment: The difference in the tests is that the third test set includes negative X or Y.

Comment: Right, but the bug should've affected test sets 1 and 2 as well, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution from Optidad Ranked 39 Qualification round

```
t = int(input())
for case in range(t):
    cj, xj, s = input().split()
    N = len(s)
    last = {"X": 0}

    for i in range(N):

        next_last = {}
        for a, v in last.items():
            if s[i] != "C":  # J or ?
                next_last["J"] = min(v + int(cj) * int(a == "C"), next_last.get("J", 9999999))
            if s[i] != "J":  # C or ?
                next_last["C"] = min(v + int(xj) * int(a == "J"), next_last.get("C", 9999999))
        last = dict(next_last)
    print(f"Case #{case + 1}: {min(last.values())}")
```

For me, this is the closest thing to DP and I find the solution very clean